# Alternative to SecurityManager for high-risk base function calls

Tags: java, securitymanager

I have a program which dynamically loads and runs class files from disk as well as remote servers.  I want to integrate a User Management system which allows me to call a user authentication method before a high-risk function call is allowed, such as reading/writing files, opening a socket, classloading, etc... The SecurityManager seems like the perfect resource to complete this, but is being removed in future releases of the JDK.  My current implementation uses a PermittedThread class that holds an authenticated User object, which is retrieved from the Thread and checked against a permissions database to ensure that this User has permission to run this high-risk function call, as shown in the code block below.

My current implementation is as such (in brief)

PermittedThread:

```
public class PermittedThread extends Thread {

    private final User user;

// Create a PermittedThread inheriting the User object from the current thread.
    public PermittedThread(Runnable target) {
        super(target);
        Thread t = currentThread();
        if (t instanceof PermittedThread) {
            user = ((PermittedThread) t).retrieveUser();
        } else
            user = null;
    }

// Create a PermittedThread with the specified User object
    public PermittedThread(Runnable target, User user) {
        super(target);
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User retrieveUser() {
        return user;
    }

}
```

From my SecurityManager:

```
    // Ensure that the current Thread is a PermittedThread, otherwise the Thread is not 
        // allowed to make high-risk function calls (user = null).
       private User checkThreadWrapping() {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        if (t instanceof PermittedThread) {
            User u = ((PermittedThread) t).retrieveUser();
            if (u != null)
                return u;
        }
        throw new SecurityException();
    }

    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission perm, Object context) {
        User threadUser = checkThreadWrapping();
                // Check if the specific User has access to this permission, and throw a 
                // SecurityException accordingly
        UserManagement.checkUserPermissionAccess(perm, threadUser);
    }
```

Without the SecurityManager, I can't imagine anyway I would be able to interrupt high-risk function calls and force an authentication check, especially on a Thread based leve.  What might be a good work around for this?

I looked into bytecode manipulation as a means of completing this as referenced by [this](https://inside.java/2021/04/23/security-and-sandboxing-post-securitymanager/) article.  However I don't believe I can modify java.base bytecode, which I would need to in order to watch for these function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Is spring AOP/AspectJ a solution to your problem?

You can wrap your own code around a high security methods and make sure that this is only allowed to be executed when something happens. You can do restcalls/db calls beforehand and its pretty simple to add to existing code.

You can create your own annotation which will be a marker for adding such a permission layer, or you can just do everything by naming.